# Java error in calculation when comparing largest and smallest numbers & sum with while loop

Tags: java, loops, count, while-loop, nested

Here is my assignment:

Write a program to read a list of nonnegative integers and to display the largest integer, the smallest integer, and the average of all the integers. The user 
indicates the end of the input by entering a negative sentinel value that is not 
used in finding the largest, smallest, and average values. The average should 
be a value of type `double` so it will be computed with a fractional part.

I've gotten different parts to work with different methods: Method A makes the maximum and minimum correct and the sum wrong and Method B makes the sum and maximum correct and  the minimum wrong. The following code demonstrates Method B. Some variables are commented out:

```
    public class testthis2
{
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        System.out.println("Enter Numbers of Nonnegative Integers.");
System.out.println("When complete, enter -1 to end input values.");
Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
//int  max = keyboard.nextInt();
int max = 0;
int min = max; //The max and min so far are the first score.
//int next = keyboard.nextInt();
int count = 0;
int sum = 0;
boolean areMore = true;
boolean run_it = false; //run it if its true
//if (max <= -1) {
 //  System.out.println("Thanks for playing!");
 //  run_it = false;
//}
// else 
// run_it = true;

while(areMore) //always true 
{

  int next = keyboard.nextInt();
   //int max = 0;
   // min = max;
  if (next < 0) { //if -1 is entered end loop.
      areMore = false;
      run_it = false;
      break; 
    }
    else //run this badboy
if(next >= max)
max = next;
else if(next <= min)
min = next;
run_it = true;
sum += next;
count++;


}
if (run_it = true) 

System.out.println("The highest score is " + max);
System.out.println("The lowest score is " + min);
System.out.println("count " + count);
System.out.println("sum " + sum);
System.out.println("average " + (double)(sum/count));
System.out.println("Thanks for playing!");        

 }

}
```

When I run this test, the maximum, sum, count, and average are all correct. However, the minimum is wrong, because 0 was clearly not entered. Here's an example test-run:

```
When complete, enter -1 to end input values.
37
25
30
20
11
14
-1
The highest score is 37
The lowest score is 0
count 6
sum 137
average 22.0
Thanks for playing!
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Could you clarify exactly what the actual and expected outputs are/should be?

Comment: so my test inputs are 37, 25, 30, 20, 11, 14, then -1 to end the loop; it works so far thanks to the peeps here, but i have a NEW problem,  I am suppose to test just the input -1 , now that i enter -1 when the prompt shows it still runs through and calculates everything when its not suppose to.  anyone care to help me on this?

Answer (score 1):

The smallest iteger is always 0 because there is no nonnegative integer that is less then 0 :)

```
if(next <= min) // for nonnegative integer this expression will return true only for 0
min = next;
```

So try to initialize the "min" variable as Integer.MAX_VALUE. I believe it will help you.

Answer (score 1):

There are 2 problems with the code:

1. You initialize `min` to 0 so it never gets updated because it will always be <= any valid number you enter.  Try initializing it to `Integer.MAX_VALUE`.  conversely also initialize `max` to `Integer.MIN_VALUE`
2. You are not correctly computing the average value: `(double)(sum/count)` will first do integer division which truncates the value THEN gets cast to double do this instead  `((double)(sum )/count)` or optionally make the type of `sum` a double.

Comment: thank you it works!  my professor also wanted me to test the value of -1 without any additional numbers entered, when i do that it still runs through, how would i fix that? (open question to anyone aswell)   when the prompt message shows i enter -1, it seems to ignore  this conditional: if (next < 0) { //if -1 is entered end loop.
      areMore = false;
      run_it = false;
      break;

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you initialize `min` and `max` both to 0.

Then the only code that will ever change `min` or `max` is based on user input.  If the input value (`next`) is `>= max`, `max` will change to that value.  This should happen on the first input.

The problem is you try setting `min` the same way.  `if (next <= min)`, but `min` was initialized to 0, so `next` can only be `<= min` if `next` is less than 0.

You need to initialize `max` and `min` on the user's first input.  They should both start equal to the user's `first` input before you compare future inputs to their value.